# Why is this curve convex?

Tags: calculus, plane-curves

I am considering the curve traced by the equation $r=a\sin 3\theta$. Specifically as $\theta$ varies from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{6}$, $r$ varies from $0$ to $a$. How do I conclude that the curve is convex in this domain? If we are dealing with cartesian coordinates for a function $y=f(x)$, the book says that the second derivative being non-negative tells us whether the function is convex or not. But is there such a test in polar coordinates for arbitrary curves? Secondly, if we allow $\theta$ to take all real values, $r$ becomes negative occasionally. Does this not contradict the meaning of r?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure they want you to use polar coordinates?  You could put $\theta$ on the x axis and r on the y axis.

Comment: $y=3\sin\,x$ and $r=3\sin\,\theta$ are very different curves. One's transcendental and unbounded, while the other's algebraic and bounded.

Comment: @DY: Yes, the equation of the curve is in polar coordinates.

Comment: Did you guys by any chance cover how to test parametrically-defined curves for convexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity assume $a=2$. In $(x,y)$-coordinates your curve then  has the parametric representation
$$\gamma:\quad \theta\ \mapsto \cases{x(\theta):=2\sin(3\theta)\cos\theta=\sin(4\theta)+\sin(2\theta) \cr
y(\theta):=2\sin(3\theta)\sin\theta=\cos(2\theta)-\cos(4\theta)\cr}\qquad(0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi).$$
To study the convexity of $\gamma$ we have to look at the sign of its curvature $\kappa$ as a function of $\theta$. Now ${\rm sgn}(\kappa)={\rm sgn}(\dot x\ddot y-\ddot x\dot y)$, where the dot denotes differentiation with respect to the parameter $\theta$. The computation gives
$$\dot x\ddot y-\ddot x\dot y=8\bigl(7+2\cos(6\theta)\bigr)>0\qquad\forall\theta\ .$$
It follows that the tangent vector $(\dot x,\dot y)$ always turns counterclockwise as $\theta$ increases. Since $(\dot x(0),\dot y(0))=(6,0)$ this implies that in the neighborhood of $\theta=0$ the curve describes a convex arc. Globally $\gamma$ is a threefoil.

Comment: $\frac{\dot{x}\ddot{y}-\ddot{x}\dot{y}}{(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2)^{3/2}}$ is the counter-clockwise curvature.

Comment: @robjohn : would using the curvature be sufficient?

Comment: @Arjang: I was simply verifying Christian's statement that $\dot{x}\ddot{y}-\ddot{x}\dot{y}$ has the same sign as the counter-clockwise curvature (positive when the curve is veering left, i.e. moving counter-clockwise). Are you asking if more is needed?

Comment: @robjohn : No, actually was asking if that is more than enough, Does curvature never changing sign and always being greater than 0 imply that the curve is convex?

Comment: @Arjang: if the curve is closed and non-self-intersecting, as is the case here, then yes. I don't know if you would consider a spiral convex.

Comment: @robjohn : That is an excellent question for one to try to generalise the concepts of Convexity, Concavity. Come to think of it now I wonder what is aspect that they try to capture by Convexity that requires all those conditions being satisfied in the first place.